# How to make doxygen show warnings only for partially documented objects

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm trying to integrate doxygen in a C++ project.
I'm using doxygen version 1.9.1

I would like that if a class/function had at least some documentation, doxygen enforced this documentation to be complete.
See the following example

```
inline void hello_foo(const std::string & world)
{
  std::cout << "Hello " << world << std::endl;
}

/**
 * @brief Test incomplete documentation
 */
inline void hello_bar(const std::string & world)
{
  std::cout << "Hello " << world << std::endl;
}
```

Here the first function (`hello_foo`) has no documentation at all.
The second function (`hello_bar`) has incomplete documentation as it's not documenting the input parameter.

I would like that doxygen generated only 1 warning on this file, i.e. the incomplete documentation in the second function.
The purpose would be to enable "warning as errors", without having to first document the whole codebase.

I tried the following configurations.
The other parameters are the default.

1. This was my first attempt, but it does not produce any warning from the above code

```
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
```

2. This configuration produces the warning I'm looking for, but it also produces warnings for the fully undocumented function.

```
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
```

Thank you

EDIT:
It looks like `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC` is ignored when  `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED=NO`, but it works otherwise.

```
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
```

this shows the missing param warnings

```
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
```

This doesn't show them.

Comment: The doxygen version 1.9.1 is from January 8, 2021. The current doxygen version is 1.10.0. About this topic there is also a small discussion tin the doxygen issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10605

Comment: Thanks. I was using 1.9.1 because that's what `apt-get install doxygen` gives you on ubuntu 22.04.
I'll give a try with the latest version

Comment: I updated to doxygen version 1.10.0 (and updated the config file), but I still get the same behavior.
I read the linked ticket but i don't see the relationship with my issue.

Comment: It looks like `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC` is ignored when  `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED=NO`. Added details to original post.

Comment: I "fixed" the problem commenting a 7-years old line in the source code.
Not sure if this is really a fix, but now it works for my use-case https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/memberdef.cpp#L4159

No

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10599